# Help with an Algebraic Proof that has Two Variables and a Square Root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Prove the following theorem.
For any positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, $x + y \geq \sqrt{ xy }$.
Answer:
First, I observe that for the special case o $x = y$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x + y &=& x + x = 2x \\
\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x^2} = x \\
2x >= x
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore the theorem is true for the special case of $x = y$. However, I do not know how to prove it for the general case. I am hoping that somebody here can tell me how to do the problem.
Thanks,
Bob

Here is a revised attempt at the proof:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 &>=& 0 \\
x + y - 2\sqrt{xy} &>=& 0 \\
x + y  &>=& 2\sqrt{xy} >= \sqrt{xy} \\
x + y &>=& \sqrt{xy}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, do I have it right?

Comment: Consider $(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)^2\ge 0$

Comment: The revised proof doesn’t have factor 2 in front of $\sqrt{xy}$. Actually, looking deeper you can conclude that it is possible to prove a stronger statement $x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ are positive, you can consider $a=\sqrt{x}$ and $b=\sqrt{y}$, so your inequality becomes
$$
a^2+b^2\ge ab
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
a^2-ab+b^2\ge0
$$
Since $a+b>0$, you can multiply by $a+b$, getting
$$
a^3+b^3\ge0
$$
which is certainly satisfied.

Alternatively, start from $(a-b)^2\ge0$, which becomes
$$
a^2+b^2\ge 2ab
$$
Since $2ab>ab$, you have $a^2+b^2>ab$ and so
$$
x+y>\sqrt{xy}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expression $x^2+xy+y^2$. Discriminant $\Delta$ of this expression is, $\Delta = 1^2-4*1*1 = -3 < 0$. Since all of the coefficients are positive, this result implies $x^2+xy+y^2 \ge 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \ ($we can conclude this by considering the elliptic paraboloid $z = x^2+xy+y^2$. It has global minimum at $(x,y) = (0,0))$. Then adding $xy$ to both sides, we have $x^2+2xy+y^2 \ge xy$. So $x+y \ge \sqrt{xy}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ (Here, we can take the square root because $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$).